# How to free space in /tmp and then move that free space to /usr?

Tags: fedora, lvm, disk

When I install Fedora, I was sure the space I gave to `/usr` was more than enough, but at the end, after I installed some development packages, I have used about 65%, which is unexpectedly much.

When I run `df -h -T`:

```
Filesystem                              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                   tmpfs     3.9G  183M  3.7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   tmpfs     3.9G  1.9M  3.9G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root ext4       24G  2.0G   21G   9% /
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-usr  ext4       11G  6.7G  3.7G  65% /usr
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-var  ext4       11G  961M  9.1G  10% /var
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-tmp  ext4      5.9G   27M  5.5G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-home ext4       23G  4.1G   18G  20% /home
/dev/sda5                               ext4      1.1G  283M  722M  29% /boot
tmpfs                                   tmpfs     791M  256K  790M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I was having problem with `/tmp` filling up in the past, so I increase it a lot, but now it seem just being used very little. So I want to take the unused disk space on `/tmp`
and move it to `/usr`.   Is that possible?

Here is when I run `vgdisplay fedora_localhost-live`:

```
VG Name               fedora_localhost-live
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                6
  Open LV               6
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <84.46 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              21621
  Alloc PE / Size       21621 / <84.46 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
```

Comment: Since you're using LVM the answer is yes. If your `/tmp` is empty you can resize it to a smaller size (`lvresize -L 100M /dev/mapper/tmp`, make sure to umount it before doing that) or delete it and recreate it with a smaller size (and remount it). After decreasing the size you should see more available space in `vgs`, resize `/usr` by executing `lvresize -L +1G /dev/mapper/usr`. Don't forget to resize the filesystem: `resize2fs /dev/mapper/usr`

Comment: should i run `unmount /dev/mapper/tmp` before i run lvresize?? i am not goood doing this

Comment: Maybe you should ask someone to help you if you're not familiar with the basic commands, messing with the filesystem can easily result in data loss. The `umount` command has to be issued on the mount point, not the logical volume: `umount /tmp` would be the command.

Comment: if i make mistake? would it broke the dual boot ? and i cant into the windows and linux since i am on dual boot now?

Comment: when i resize2fs i got this `resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-tmp`

Comment: I'd leave `/tmp` alone and merge `/usr` into `/` instead... but it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: i already run on the stesp the first comment, and i got that my last comment, help me, :( what's wrong with it?

Comment: Alright, I'll explain step by step:
    1. make sure nothing important is in `/tmp`
    2. run `umount /tmp` (and check it worked)
    3. run `lvresize -L 100M /dev/mapper/tmp`
    4. run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/tmp`
    5. run `mount /tmp`

Comment: @eblock please don't do this in the comments. Post an answer explaining the steps instead. Also, why do you need to issue the `umount` on the mount point? Either `umount /dev/sda1` or`umount /mnt/foo` should work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following steps to reduce the size of `/tmp`, I tried doing it online with this output (lv `test` is mounted in `/mnt`):

```
server1:~ # lvresize --resizefs -L 100M /dev/vg01/test 
Do you want to unmount "/mnt" ? [Y|n] y
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
/dev/mapper/vg01-test: 12/102400 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 30311/409600 blocks
resize2fs 1.43.8 (1-Jan-2018)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg01-test to 102400 (1k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg01-test is now 102400 (1k) blocks long.

  Size of logical volume vg01/test changed from 400.00 MiB (100 extents) to 100.00 MiB (25 extents).
  Logical volume vg01/test successfully resized.
```

So it unmounts it for you, it seems. The new size is reflected in the output of `df -h`:

```
server1:~ # df -h | grep mnt
/dev/mapper/vg01-test       89M  8.3M   74M  11% /mnt
```

If that procedure works for you, try to increase `/usr`:

1. run `lvresize -L +1G /dev/mapper/usr`
2. run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/usr`
3. check with `df -h` if the change was applied

If decreasing the size of `/tmp` did not work, edit your question and post all the commands you issued including their output.

Comment: the `resize2fs` shrinking has to be done *before* shrinking LV...  for ext4 you can use `lvresize --resizefs` to do both together in one command

Comment: I've never tried to shrink a filesystem, I edited the answer.

Comment: well i can increase /usr now , but when i check `df -h` i didnt see the `/tmp` filesyetem anymore? where is that? i alread umount and mount /tmp thought

Comment: What happens when you run `mount /tmp`? Update the question to add that information.